# Create an index for a class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class called undergrad which keeps track of students first and last names. I would like each object to have an index. In my program class, I create a `List<>` of undergrads. How would I set it so each object in the list has a unique identifying number, and what would it look like in the program class?

```
public class Undergrad
{
     String fName, lName;

     public Undergrad()
     {
     }

     public Undergrad(string firstName, string lastName)
     {
         this.fName = firstName;
         this.lName = lastName;           
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to assign an index that is valid only in your list? There you can just use the index of the item in the list that is already available. Do you store the students somewhere (database)?

Comment: No, I dont store them anywhere. I'm quite new to programming, I figured creating soem kind of index method in the class would be the simplist way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to add a property to the class to store that index for starters. This could either be an integer or a UniqueIdentifer.

If you go with an integer, you'll need somewhere else (such as a database) to store all the indices so that you're application knows where to get the next value at.

With a UniqueIdentifer (System.Guid) you won't get duplicate collisions so you could just create that inline.

**OPTION 1**

```
public class Undergrad
{
     String fName, lName;
     public Guid UniqueId {get; set; }

     public Undergrad()
     {
          UniqueId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
     }

     public Undergrad(string firstName, string lastName)
     {   
         UniqueId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
         this.fName = firstName;
         this.lName = lastName;           
     }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
public class Undergrad
{
     String fName, lName;
     public int UniqueId {get; set; }

     public Undergrad()
     {
          UniqueId = //LoadFromDatabase();
     }

     public Undergrad(string firstName, string lastName)
     {   
         UniqueId = //LoadFromDatabase();
         this.fName = firstName;
         this.lName = lastName;           
     }
}
```

Where are you currently storing your undergrad information ? if it's in a database already, I'd expect you to have an id field on the object already.

Last thing, when you put these into a `List<T>`, the list will have it's own index (for position within the list) which is a separate concept.

Comment: Thanks Eoin- If I use option one, will the unique ID be asssigned automatically in the program class?

Comment: correct. in the example I gave a new ID is generated each time in the class constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `static` unique ID to the class.

```
public class Undergrad
{
     String fName, lName;
     private static int _uniqueID;   
     private int _myUniqueID;

     public Undergrad() : this(string.Empty, string.Empty)
     {

     }

     public Undergrad(string firstName, string lastName) 
     {
         this.fName = firstName;
         this.lName = lastName;          

         _uniqueID += 1; 
         _myUniqueID = _uniqueID;
     }

    public int UniqueID { get { return _myUniqueID; } }
}
```

Comment: Isn't an instance ID field missing ?

Comment: This will return the current `_uniqueID` for each instance of `Undergrad`.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually, static variables in C# are shared amongst all instances of the same type. Try it out yourself, works fine for me.

Comment: Yes and that causes the exact problem I address. Create 2 instances of `Undergrad`, both will report 2 as `UniqueID`. As @SteveB suggests, store the value of `_uniqueID` in an instance field.

Comment: @CodeCaster I was originally testing it with for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { var a = new UnderGrad(); Console.WriteLine(a.UniqueID); } and that worked fine, with UniqueID showing incrementing numbers, but when I instantiated separately using different variables, it showed 2, 2 as you stated. Is it because my test, it was using the same reference variable?

Comment: No, because the `_uniqueID` returns the amount of objects created since application start. In each iteration a new object gets created, increasing the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but:

You could create an object that will contain the list of Undergrad, add an enum class EUndergrad for example and add the indexing method that will return the instance you're looking for.

```
public class Undergrads
{
    private List<Undergrad> myList;

    public Undergrad this[EUndergrad index]
    {
        return this.myList[index];
    }
}

public enum EUndergrad
{
    Undergrad_0 = 0,
    Undergrad_1 = 1,
    ...
}
```

And you can retrieve your Undergrad object by calling

```
instanceOfUndergrads[EUndergrad.Undergrad_0]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Maintain a lookup of your list and assign a unique id/guid as key for that lookup**

```
    public class Undergrad
    {
        String fName, lName;

        public Undergrad()
        {
        }

        public Undergrad(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            this.fName = firstName;
            this.lName = lastName;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Undergrad> lstGraduates = new List<Undergrad>() { new Undergrad("f1", "l1"), new Undergrad("f2", "l2"), new Undergrad("f3", "l3") };
            int i = 0;
            ILookup<int, Undergrad> lookup = lstGraduates.ToLookup(p => i++);

            foreach (IGrouping<int, Undergrad> packageGroup in lookup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(packageGroup.Key);
                Undergrad obj = (Undergrad)packageGroup;                
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Try this out** - or explain what it does?

Comment: @CodeCaster - I have added the comments, sorry but I thought that the code is self explainatory.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy to [Generating Unique Keys in .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14403/Generating-Unique-Keys-in-Net)

You can include KeyGenerator that provides unique keys.

```
public class Undergrad
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Undergrad()
    {
        Id = KeyGenerator.GetUniqueKey();
    }

    public Undergrad(string firstName, string lastName)
        : this()
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}

public static class KeyGenerator
{
    public static string GetUniqueKey()
    {
        int maxSize = 8;
        int minSize = 5;
        var chars = new char[62];
        string a;
        a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        chars = a.ToCharArray();
        int size = maxSize;
        var data = new byte[1];
        var crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        size = maxSize;
        data = new byte[size];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        var result = new StringBuilder(size);
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            result.Append(chars[b%(chars.Length - 1)]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Test:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((new Undergrad()).Id);
        Console.WriteLine((new Undergrad()).Id);
        Console.WriteLine((new Undergrad()).Id);
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
    QdfQcGuV
    5MtEBtev
    AXwseCmJ
```